# How can I send /#/pagetitle to /pagetitle?

Tags: .htaccess

I need some help writing a `.htaccess` file.

I'm using a Flash based theme and it creates URLs like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/#/pagetitle
```

How can I redirect these to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/pagetitle
```

?

Answer (score 4):

Apache (and anything that runs serverside) can not access anything after `#`; that part is the [*fragment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) and available to client side only (JavaScript).

You will need to use JavaScript to access that programmaticly.

Comment: No server can access the fragment. This is not specific to Apache: it's simply not sent with the HTTP request.

Comment: @Radek I didn't say *Apache exclusively* can't access it.

Comment: me neither, but I say this to prevent people from thinking you do :)